# Duplicate Rows when Summing and grouping by col

Tags: sql-server

How I can create a single Row for each Account By Department, I mean the total amount?

```
SELECT  Account
  , AccountName,
    Department,
    Company,
    isNull(VendorCode,'') as VendorCode,
    isNull(UPPER(VendorName),'') as VendorName,
    isNull(ProjectCode,'') as ProjectCode,
    isNull(UPPER(ProjectName),'') as ProjectName,
    FiscalYear,
    FiscalPeriod,
    Sum(Amount)as Amount
FROM [GL]
group by Account, AccountName, Department, Company, VendorCode, VendorName, ProjectCode, ProjectName, FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod
order by AccountName, Department, Company asc
--group by X.Account, x.AccountName, Department, Company, x.VendorCode, x.VendorName, x.ProjectCode, x.ProjectName, x.FiscalYear, x.FiscalPeriod, x.Amount
```

GO

[image]

Comment: Why not just need to remove the columns you don't need from the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you could provide sample data and expected results as tabular text.

Answer (score 0):

**If** I followed you correctly, you just need to remove the columns you don't need from the `GROUP BY` clause. If you want the total amount per

```
SELECT AccountName, Department, SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM [GL]
GROUP BY AccountName, Department
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is **You are select redundant property like `Company`, `VendorCode`, `VendorName`, etc.**

As a result, You can see the same `Account` 9999 but different `Company`

So if I were in your shoes, I would group by the property that I need

```
SELECT AccountName, Department, SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM [GL]
GROUP BY AccountName, Department
ORDER BY AccountName, Department
```